# C# binary tree node setter called multiple times

Tags: c#, exception, tree, getter-setter

Hello I do not know why in my implementation the setter is called more than once or how can I prevent this?

```
class Node<T> {
    public T _value { get; set; }
    public Node<T> _left
    {
        set
        { System.Console.WriteLine("setter called");_left = value; }
    }
    public Node<T> _right
    {
        set
        { System.Console.WriteLine("setter called"); _right = value; }
    }

    public Node(T value){
        _value = value;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Node<int> a = new Node<int>(1);
        Node<int> b = new Node<int>(3);

        a._left = b;

        System.Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Why is the setter again invoked within the setter itself? I can prevent this problem by writing an method that sets the Node but I would like to know how it is done by the C# getters setters...

By the way the resulting exeption is a StackOverflow

Comment: Your setter is calling itself, `_left` invokes `_left` invokes `_left` invokes `_left`...

If you want to sat the value of a backing field, you need to create the backing field.

Answer (score 0):

You got stack overflow because you have infinite recursion here. i'll will explain why

in this line  Node a = new Node(1); you are call to constructor i.e to the this line _value = value; in this line you call to the public Node _left method and in the implementation of this method you do **recursive call** (call from method to itslef) by the following code ;_left = value;

The solution is:

```
public class Node<T> {
    public T Value { get; set; }

    private Node<T> _left;
    public Node<T> Left
    {
        set
        { System.Console.WriteLine("setter called");_left = value; }
    }
    private Node<T> _right;
    public Node<T> Right
    {
        set
        { System.Console.WriteLine("setter called"); _right = value; }
    }

    public Node(T value){
        Value = value;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Node<int> a = new Node<int>(1);
        Node<int> b = new Node<int>(3);

        a.Left = b;

        System.Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```